# How to refresh data in frontend using React Native?

Tags: mongodb, react-native

I am using useSWR hook in Next.js and refreshInterval as a parameter to update the data from MongoDB database. When for example another user adds a comment, it will be updated on the screen.

Now I want to get the same behaviour in React Native using Node/Express server as a backend.

What should I do?

1. Send a request to the backend e.g. every second and check if there were changes? I suppose useSWR works like this.
2. Push the notification somehow starting with MongoDB and then from Node/Express to Android / iOS device? How to do it?

I am considering, which is the best solution, but have no idea at the time.

Comment: Yep, option 1 is called long polling. If you are not sending much data then it's an ok solution.

Another option is to use websockets. Take a look at https://socket.io/

Comment: Here's some stuff you can read https://ably.com/blog/websockets-vs-long-polling#:~:text=Long%20polling%20is%20more%20resource,hops%20between%20servers%20and%20devices.

Comment: Thanks. The problem with web sockets is, that the node/express server is stateless and knows nothing about the logged in users. It will not know, where to send  the push notifications. I think, only the first solution makes sense. Or am I wrong?